# Can $\bigoplus_{n\geq 0}H^0(X,K_X^{-n}) $ fail to be finitely generated?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there an example of a smooth projective variety $X$ (say, over $\mathbb{C}$) such that the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $\bigoplus_{n\geq 0}H^0(X,K_X^{-n}) $ is not finitely generated?

Comment: I remember a claim in some paper that general ruled surface over a hyperbolic curve has infinitely generated anticanonical ring; quick search tells that this result should be in Fumio Sakai, Anti-Kodaira dimension of ruled surfaces, Sci. Rep. Saitama Univ. Ser. A
10, no.2, 1–7. (1982), but I could not find this paper anywhere.

Comment: @Denis T: Thank you very much! I couldn't find the paper either, but in *Finite generation of a canonical ring* Kawamata  indeed mentions this result of Sakai. I will try to locate that paper.

Comment: I believe this also holds for the $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over an elliptic K3 surface associated to the nontrivial extension of the structure sheaf by the invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}(F)$ of an elliptic curve fiber $F$.

Comment: @Jason Starr: I am confused, it seems to me that $H^1(\mathscr{O}(F))=0$ on an elliptic K3 surface?

Comment: Yes, I should have written $\mathcal{O}(2F)$ not $\mathcal{O}(F)$.

Comment: Also, in the (smooth) moduli stack of rank $2$ locally free sheaves on a hyperbolic curve, there should be a dense open substack where the anticanonical $\mathbb{C}$-algebra is just $\mathbb{C}$ (and thus trivially finitely generated).  Those where the anticanonical rings is not trivial have to be rather special (but I believe that they do exist).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chenyang Xu claims that $X = \mathbb{P}_S\left(\mathcal{O}_S \oplus \mathcal{O}_S(H) \right)$, where $S$ the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ along $9$ general points and  $H$ is any ample Cartier divisor on $S$, provides such an example. See example 3.8 in his paper [K-stability for varieties with a big anti-canonical class](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.16631.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! This example is indeed quite simple.